# How to select a seam area from the 3d viewport?

Tags: uv

Say that I'm doing some UV mapping on the left part of the screen and I have the 3d perspective view on my right, I want to choose (inside the 3d view area) which seamed faces I want to UV map next, so how can I select all of the faces that make up the seamed area? I already seamed up the area, so how do I select it?

Do I have to manually select face by face to get the "seamed island"? If I just press A, I do get the seamed area to show up as an island in the UV editor, everything is great, but then of course everything else shows up, all other faces on the object, but I just want the seamed area to show up, nothing else, but without having to select each and every "member" face of the seamed area.

I'm not sure if UV mapping is best done by selecting faces in the 3d view part and then switching to UV editor or is it just me, but I find it billion times easier that pressing A and sorting out what is what in the UV editor. I started using Blender just a few days ago, so I still have a lot of learn, so if anyone can recommend a great tutorial place, maybe a youtube channel, it would really help.